# Is there a general solution to $\dot x = f(x)+g(t)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general solution to $\dot x = f(x)+g(t)$? (for arbitrary continuously differentiable $f$ and $g$).

You can just give me the name of this kind of ODE/solution method, so that I can find out about the solution myself.

Comment: This is a first order nonlinear (or in some cases of $f$ linear) differential equation.

Comment: yes, but it does have some particular structure, and I'm wondering whether this particular structure allows you to find a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is a linear function of $x$, (i.e. $f(x)=mx$), then the solution is $x=e^{-mt}+h(t)$ where $h$ depends on $g$. There are specific solutions to other cases of $f$ and $g$, some of them well studied.

As far as general solutions, they do not exist. Allowing arbitrary $f$ and $g$ means that you can use some really pathological functions. Imagine if $f$ was the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) and $g$ was the [Cantor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Comment: Ok, assume then that $f$ and $g$ are continuously differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Your ''general solution'' is the integral formulation of Cauchy Problem.

Let $f(x)+g(t)=h(t,x)$ and $x:[t_{0},t]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a solution (if exist)

Then $x(t)-x(t_{0})=\int_{t_{0}}^{t}{h(s,x(s))\textrm{d}s}$. (Fund.Theorem of Calculus).

Comment: I don't see how this helps, because $x$ is still in the integral. The whole problem of solving ODE's is trying to get the $x$ only on the left side, and let the right side be a function of $t$ only.

Comment: Yes, but this is a general solution for arbitrary $f,g$. If you don't specify the functions, we cannot get a closed formulae.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can solve this equation for arbitrary functions $f$ and $g$. In some cases, you might be able to integrate this equation by the method of eulerian multipliers (aka integrating factor).

Let us call $h(x(t),t)=-f(x)-g(t)$, then your ODE can be rewritten as:

$$h(x(t),t)+\dot{x}=0.$$

In some cases, one might come up with a eulerian multiplier $e(x(t),t)\neq 0$ for all $t$ and $x(t)$ such that by multiplying the ODE by $e(x(t),t)$ results in an exact differential equation

$$e(x(t),t)h(x(t),t)+e(x(t),t)\dot{x}=0$$

The function $e(x(t),t)$ is a eulerian multiplier if it is a solution to the following partial differential equation:

$$\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x} \left[eh\right] = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}e.$$

In most cases this partial differential equation is also difficult to solve, so one can use ansatz functions like $e=e(x)$, $e=e(t)$, $e=e(x+t)$, $e=e(xt)$ and so forth.

If a eulerian multiplier is found one can construct a potential to the ODE by integrating

$$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\Phi(x,t) = eh \qquad \text{and} \qquad \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\Phi(x,t) = e.$$

After having found the potential we know that $$\Phi(x,t)=\text{const.}$$ 
So the last problem is to solve this algebraic equation for $x(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

Even for innocent-looking functions such as $f(x) = x^3$, $g(t) = t^3$, there seems to be no closed-form solution.  At least, none that Maple finds.